# Using For each In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have this table in my database:

`StudentExam`:

```
studentID, ExamID, EarnedMarks, Status
```

I want a query that returns (foreach examID check status, if 'done' return ExamID else return nothing.)

That means every student had attended the exam.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bring back all ExamId where all it's associated status are `Done` one way would be

```
SELECT ExamId 
FROM   StudentExam 
GROUP  BY ExamId 
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN Status = 'DONE' THEN 1 
                      END)
```

Or another

```
SELECT ExamId 
FROM   StudentExam 
WHERE  Status = 'DONE' 
EXCEPT 
SELECT ExamId 
FROM   StudentExam 
WHERE  Status <> 'DONE' 
        OR Status IS NULL
```